# Does @x ||= work like return @x if @x.present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is this:

```
def x?
  return @x if @x.present?

  @x = #boolean calculation
end
```

Equivalent to this for boolean values of `@x`?

```
def x?
  @x ||= #boolean calculation
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use either option for memoizing `boolean` values as both will recalculate if `@x` is `false`.

`present?` is a special kind of rails check that equates to `!blank?` and `false.blank? #=> true` but even if this was not a boolean check `present?` and `||` are not equivalent. For objects that implement `empty?` blank defers to that so something that is `empty?` is also `blank?` and thus is not `present?`.

```
"".present? #=> false
"" || true #=> "" 
[].present? #=> false
[] || true #=> [] 
false.present? #=> false
false || true #=> true
```

`@x ||= some_logic` equates to `@x = @x || some_logic` where obviously if `@x` is false `some_logic` will fire.

If you just want to see if `@x` has already been determined to be a value (e.g. not `nil`) then you could replace this with

```
def x? 
  return @x unless @x.nil? 
  @x = some_logic
end
```

Comment: I did notice it would recalculate on a false for both cases, but I'm not sure if that's intended behaviour. Good point about memoizing boolean values though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

```rb
@x ||= value
```

is equivalent to

```rb
@x = @x || value
```

which assigns `value` to `@x` only if `@x` is falsy. In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are falsy.

Further, `#present?` is a concept from Rails (see [doc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)).

Note though that depending on the value that you expect to store in `@x`, it *might* be equivalent. `#present?` is simply the negation of `#blank?` (also a Rails concept). `#blank?` is defined on `Object` as follows:

```rb
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```

Thus, the behavior of the two snippets you posted is guaranteed to be equivalent when `@x` contains a value that doesn't define its own `#present?`, `#blank?`, or `#empty?` methods.

Now, `FalseClass` and `NilClass` both define `#blank?`:

```rb
def blank?
  true
end
```

`TrueClass` also defines `#blank?`:

```rb
def blank?
  false
end
```

But this is just an optimization as the default implementation from `Object` would result in the same values.

Therefore, `false` and `nil` will return `false` for `#present?` and `true` will return `true` for `#present?`.

From this we conclude that, in the specific case of storing boolean values in `@x`, the behavior of the two snippets is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: No**

Just to add more examples to the answers already above:

```
def x1?(new_value)
  return @x if @x.present?

  @x = new_value
end

def x2?(new_value)
  @x ||= new_value
end
```

say `@x` was a Number:

```
@x = 123
x1?('new value')
@x
# => 123

@x = 123
x2?('new value')
@x
# => 123

# 123 == 123, so this works for `Number`
```

but let's say `@x` was an empty Array:

```
@x = []
x1?('new value')
@x
# => 'new value'

@x = []
x2?('new value')
@x
# => []

# 'new value' != [], so it doesn't work for empty Array.
```

^ and there are all other "types" that this doesn't work as well not just empty Array, some of which have already been answered by others here.